# Create database software with cocoa

Tags: database, cocoa, relational-database

I'm looking to create software for Mac which is the front-end for a locally-created database.

What's the best way for me to do this in Cocoa?

Some more information:

- The database will start simple, but eventually be fairly complex (I have 2-300 tables in my projected schema).
- I want to save the database as a file (or bundle), so that from the user's perspective it's just a document.
- I'm really just starting out with Cocoa, should I'd like to use a method that has a decent learning curve (so probably something built-into cocoa)
- Potentially this would have to be distributed through the mac app store (sigh)

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is an option, but it's not without trade offs. It's more or less a single-user solution. You *can* write multi-user apps with it, but unlike (say) Oracle or PostgreSQL, which are client-server from the start, you'd have to write your own server app that would marshal the client requests. It also (intentionally, by design) makes it difficult to gain direct SQL access to the underlying data store.

On the other hand, the learning curve is easy, and it's part of Cocoa and well-integrated into the standard document-based architecture.

Comment: Also - I presume that something written to use CoreData could be leveraged fairly easily in the future to act as a client to (for example) a web-based server

Comment: I don't think I'd make that presumption. Core Data is tied pretty closely to its own data sources, and expects the underlying database schema (if there is one - XML stores can also be used) to be a private implementation detail. It's not very well suited to building clients that connect to existing databases.